# How can we detect system volume in WIndows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

If I have an app that plays sounds.  It seems like a good idea to indicate why the user isn't hearing the sounds. Is there a way to detect system volume or MUTE?

Comment: @neoistheone - Aren't those desktop related APIs? Or are they also allowed in Store apps?

Comment: @neoistheone - But would they work in Store Apps? Store Apps are sandboxed so I'm not sure if these APIs would be accessible (they may be).

Comment: @keyboardP, from that vantage point I would tend to agree with you (i.e. they are probably not accessible via a store app). Or at least not directly like that. Good call.

Comment: I could p/invoke in my Store app. But that would disqualify ARM devices.

Comment: @keyboardP, here is the listing of windows store app APIs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205762.aspx. Interestingly enough there is an analogous one **and** it works on Windows Phone 8.

Comment: So what *exactly* is the `- MSFT` in your user name supposed to mean?  It implies access to better resources than SO, for questions like this.

Comment: @neoistheone Ah nice, thanks for the link!

Comment: @BenVoigt He works for Microsoft as Developer Evangelist

Comment: Desktop apps are able to via [SharpDx's SimpleAudioVolume class](http://www.sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-mediafoundation-simpleaudiovolume), which relies upon some [unmanaged calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb970319.aspx).

Comment: The WinRT interfaces only support per-application volume control.  Endpoint volume control as done with WASAPI with the IAudioEndpointVolume interface is still on the [approved list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452756.aspx).

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, "- MSFT" means Microsoft. But what resource can beat SO? :) Plus these are questions that if I simply answer them myself, how is the community benefited? I am sure you understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

- [`MediaControl.SoundLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediacontrol.soundlevel.aspx) for Windows 8
- [`SystemMediaTransportControls.SoundLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols.soundlevel.aspx) for Windows 8.1 and later

> Music and media capture apps should monitor the SoundLevel to determine whether the audio streams on the app have been Muted.

Comment: SystemMediatTransportControls.SoundLevel only works in 8.1, but great find! This may be the answer, but you should amend to point out it works on 8.1 only. MediaControl.SoundLevel should work up until 8.1, after which you'll have to switch.

Comment: @Nate: That's why I provided links to both versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Windows.Media` namespace. Also these is `SoundLevel` enum.

Also

[ISimpleAudioVolume interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dd316531.aspx)